# Android - How to hide ActionBarCombat

Tags: android, android-layout

I made use of the ActionBarCombat to have a compatible ActionBar across different OS versions. Every thing works OK, but I want to have the Action Bar displayed only on tablets.

Based on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and on device screen size (`size >=7 inch`), I'm determining that the device is a tablet.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
//........
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
                    && isTablet()) {

                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "OK - display ActionBar");
                ActionBarHelper.createInstance(this);

            } else {
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Do not display ActionBar: SDK_INT: "
                        + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT); //
            }
//......
}
```

The problem is that if the device is not a tablet, (so the `ActionBarHelper.createInstance(this);` does not get called, the action bar is still displayed. And I can't figure out why?

However I noticed one thing. If I open the main.xml layout file in the graphical mode, I see the action bar displayed on top, but when I open the layout file in source mode, there isn't.

Do you know guys how to hide the ActionBarCombat?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, probably, can create `ActionBarHelperDummy` extending `ActionBarHelper`. That `ActionBarHelperDummy` will do nothing for every abstract function it inherits from `ActionBarHelper`.

This way you will have a concrete class extending `ActionBarHelper` and doing nothing.

Then in `ActionBarHelper.createInstance()` you will be returning `ActionBarHelperDummy` in case `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB`

Comment: Thank you. That is a nice trick.
I managed to hide it by applying a theme style.